# Endless rotating in CCD

Tags: c++, animation, game-engine, inverse-kinematics, cyclic-coordinate-descent

Heya
I'm currently working on my Degree Final year project, which is 2 part A) Creating a good 3D Engine and B) within it implement an IK System and evaluate a couple of types of IK solving.
CCD (Cyclic-Coordinate Descent) is where I have begun and I have run into a problem.
I've used lots of sources to try and get to grips with IK's, and specifically when it comes to CCD I have used Source Code as a base available here : http://www.darwin3d.com/gdm1998.htm

Before I start posting my Source code, I'm hoping that my problem is something obvious or simple that someone has come across before. 
Here is a short video showing the problem : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtU8rFR-DuE

Obviously it is not right, The IK spins off and generally seems to get confused alot!
If the target stays still then it converges fine but even the smallest movement (which happens alot in this system as the Target is driven by IR based Motion capture in my Engine) and it seems to recalculate and begin the spinning again.

Also when the Joint is out of range you would assume that following CCD technique, the Joints would all point at the Target and just hit the Loop limit but you would still have the IK aim in the right way, but as is evident in the video if the target is out of range the IK again just sits iterating away and spinning.

If anyone can help I would Really! appreciate it.
and if any more information is needed (code etc) then feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Tons of things could be wrong; you have to debug your program.

For each joint:

1. Retrieve the target position `target` and the end-effector position `end`.
2. Calculate the new joint value `q`, knowing the transformation of the joint.
3. Compute the end-effector position `endNew` for the new joint value `q`.

If the distance from `end` to `target` is smaller than the distance from `endNew` to `target`, you have found a bug (all spinning is wrong). Either the bug is in the selection of `q` in 2. or in the computation of end-effector positions in 1. and 3.

I'd be reluctant to use other peoples random example code ([or even my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625390/2d-inverse-kinematics-implementation/4514937#4514937)). Lander for example writes

```
CrossProduct(&curVector, &targetVector, &crossResult);
NormalizeVector(&crossResult);
```

but are we sure that this won't crash with a division by zero (say, if `curVector = -targetVector`)?

If the joints are revolute (and not spherical as in Lander's example), then see Wang & Chen in Lander's references for the math.